# Subsonic Three (3) CreatedBy fields not updating

Tags: subsonic

Using Subsonic 3 I have the fields:

```
      o CreatedOn (datetime)
      o CreatedBy (nvarchar(50))
      o ModifiedOn (datetime)
      o ModifiedBy (nvarchar(50))
```

When I add data to my table it is not adding data to these columns. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fields aren't automatically populated in version 3 like they were in version 2, unless you are using the ActiveRecord templates. You could modify the templates pretty simply to add the functionality yourself.

Comment: Would you not have to modify the source rather than templates?

Comment: No need to modify the source, you could simply modify the Context.tt files to auto populate the required fields before calling update/insert.

Comment: I am now using the ActiveRecord templates that have them in but when I call repository.add these fields are still not being populated

Comment: If you call the ActiveRecord.Add method are the fields populated? 
Have a look in your generated ActiveRecord classes and you should see the fields being populated in the Updated and Add methods.

Comment: If I call ACtiverecord.Add then they get populated