# Entity Framework CreatedBy fields not updating

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Using Entity Framework I have the fields:

```
  o CreatedOn (datetime)
  o CreatedBy (nvarchar(50))
  o ModifiedOn (datetime)
  o ModifiedBy (nvarchar(50))
```

When I add data to my table it is not adding/updating data to these columns. Am I missing something?

This is a similar question to [subsonic CreatedBy fields not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843062/subsonic-three-3-createdby-fields-not-updating)

Comment: What mechanism do you expect to create these?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a mechanism to create/update these in EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the EF will automatically populate these. You can do it on the DB server or in code (e.g., in a Repository).